# Convert into Java 8 Lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am very new to lambda. Can someone please help in converting following nested loops in lambda -

```
for (Question question : questionList) {
        formattedText += NEW_LINE + localizeString(QUESTION_STRING_ID) + question.getQuestionText();
        formattedText += NEW_LINE + localizeString(ANSWER_STRING_ID);
        for (Answer answer : question.getAnswers()) {
            formattedText += answer.getAnswerText() + NEW_LINE;
        }
    }
```

Solution I tried

```
for (Question question : questionList) {
        formattedText += NEW_LINE + localizeString(QUESTION_STRING_ID) + question.getQuestionText();
        formattedText += NEW_LINE + localizeString(ANSWER_STRING_ID);
        question.getAnswers().forEach(answer -> {formattedText += answer.getAnswerText() + NEW_LINE;});
}
```

Not sure how can I convert both loops into single lambda expression? Also, this solution is not working since it needs formattedText to be declared as final.

Answer (score 3):

It may be implemented using `Collectors.joining` collector of Stream API:

```java
String prefixQ =  NEW_LINE + localizeString(QUESTION_STRING_ID);
String suffixQ =  NEW_LINE + localizeString(ANSWER_STRING_ID);
String result = questionList.stream()
    .map(q -> 
            prefixQ + q.getQuestionText() + suffixQ 
            + q.getAnswers().stream()
                    .map(Answer::getAnswerText)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(NEW_LINE))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.joining(NEW_LINE));
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a `Collector`.  For example,

```
for (Question question : questionList) {
        formattedText += NEW_LINE + localizeString(QUESTION_STRING_ID) + question.getQuestionText();
        formattedText += NEW_LINE + localizeString(ANSWER_STRING_ID);
        formattedText +=
                question.getAnswers()
                        .stream()
                        .map(Answer::getAnswerText)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(NEW_LINE));
        formattedText += NEW_LINE;
}
```

That supposes that `NEW_LINE` represents a `String`.  If instead it is a character then you could use `String.valueOf(NEWLINE)` as the argument to `Collectors.joining()`.

Do note, however, that there is not actually any lambda in that at all.  The one place where one might have been used, I use a method reference instead.